# PHP Using while loop to count rows

Tags: php, pdo

I'm attempting to show notifications when one user follows another user. I want to check the notification table to see when the receive_id is the same as the logged in users id ($user_id). The issue is that I'm not sure how to write the while loop to check how many times these values are the same. Currently, the loop is unending. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM notif_follow WHERE receive_id=:rid ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->execute(array(":rid"=>$user_id));
$notif = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$id = $notif['id'];
$send_id = $notif['send_id'];
$receive_id = $notif['receive_id'];
$status = $notif['status'];

if($notif !== false)
 {
  while($receive_id = $user_id)
  {
   echo '
   <li>
    <a href="#">
     <strong>'.$notif['send_name'].'</strong><br />
     <small><em>'.$notif['receive_name'].'</em></small>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<li><a href="#" class="text-bold text-italic">No Notification Found</a></li>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: `while($receive_id = $user_id)` This is an assignment. Use `==` or `===` for a comparison.

Comment: Also, you're not actually looping over anything, you're just grabbing the first item from the result set and then eternally checking it over and over. You'll need to call `fetch()` more than once.

Comment: Would fetchAll be appropriate?

Comment: Why you use this while($receive_id **==** $user_id)??? this condition is already set in your SQL select statement... change it with **foreach($nofif as $elmt)** . Change also you fetch with fetchAll and check that you only need 5 results (if it's more change your "LIMIT" value)

Comment: What is `runQuery()` Thats not vanilla PDO so we need to see what it is doing!

Comment: Your solution worked Benfarhat, thank you.